# Print the values which are smaller than a number entered by the user

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have a file called files.txt, where I have the following data:

1;400;33000;garden kitchen

11;178;56124;bathroom roof

7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen

10;150;1000000;garage yard

I need to enter in a number and compare it with the 3rd column of each line. If the value in the 3rd column is smaller it prints out the row, otherwise it does nothing.

For example if I read in the number 50000, the program should print:

1;400;33000;garden kitchen

7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen

Here is my code so far:

```
$num = Read-Host "Enter a number"
             $t = Get-content "files.txt" | %{$_.split(";")[2]} 
              for($i = 0; $i -le $t.Length; $i++)
             {
                 if ($num -ge $t[$i])
                 {
                   write-host $t[$i]
                 }
             }
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the split later. Right now your are throwing all the other columns away. I would also do a foreach:

```
# making the type int, will validate the input
[int]$num = Read-Host "Enter a number"
$lines = Get-content "files.txt"

foreach($line in $lines) {
    $parts = $line -split ';'

    # make sure we have enough parts
    if($parts.Length -ge 4) {
        # we have enough
        # [int] is not really needed here, but it adds clarity
        if($num -ge [int]$parts[2]) {
            Write-Output $line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be easier if you treat your file as a CSV, and just import it with custom headers.

```
$t = Import-Csv files.txt -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'
```

At this point you have objects for each line that would look like this:

```
Col1 : 1
Col2 : 400
Col3 : 33000
Col4 : garden kitchen

Col1 : 11
Col2 : 178
Col3 : 56124
Col4 : bathroom roof

Col1 : 7
Col2 : 777
Col3 : 20000
Col4 : oneroom kitchen

Col1 : 10
Col2 : 150
Col3 : 1000000
Col4 : garage yard
```

Now you just ask for a number (make sure to cast it as `[int]` or PowerShell will think it is a string and not compare it like a number when the time comes), and iterate `$t` filtering for your criteria with a `Where` statement (and convert it back to the format you expect, skipping the first line to omit the headers we setup):

```
[int]$num = Read-Host "Enter a number"
$t|?{$num -gt $_.Col3}|ConvertTo-Csv -del ';' -NoTypeInformation|Select -skip 1
```

Answer (score 1):

i presume you are using ps5.1+ since you didn't mention a version. this requires version 4+ to use `.Where()` instead of `Where-Object`.

this does NOT verify that the user input is an int. if you need that it's simple enuf to add. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
1;400;1000000;garden kitchen
11;178;56124;bathroom roof
7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen
10;150;1000000;garage yard
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Choice = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a lower-limit number '

$InStuff.Where({[int]$_.Split(';')[2] -ge [int]$Choice})
```

output ...

```
Please enter a lower-limit number : 123456
1;400;1000000;garden kitchen
10;150;1000000;garage yard
```

Comment: Simple and nice solution, I like it :)

Comment: @TylerJoe - thank you! i had fun working it out ... [*grin*]